# What are natural ways to say that the kettle I started has just reached a boiling point?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Let's say I started a kettle and it has just reached a boiling point. And then my friend comes up to the kettle, not knowing it has just boiled the water, to turn it on. What the most natural way to say that the water has just reached a boiling? Which of the following sentences sound the most natural?

> It just **boiled**.
>
> I just **boiled up**.
>
> It just **went off**.
>
> It just **turn off**.

I would like to know American and British ways to say it.

Comment: I am British and I would say 'it has just boiled'.

Comment: In other circumstances than described, the kettle has "come to the boil."

Comment: I think a really simple way to say it would be "**It's done boiling.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just boiled, or It has (It's) just boiled, would seem to be the simplest.

It's just turned off, or It's just finished (boiling) are quite acceptable alternatives.  (Those It's are short for "It has")

You could also use something like "It's still hot"

It is reasonable to use the present perfect in this case, to describe the present state of the kettle resulting from the past boil.